# Using jQuery, how to find out if CSS selector "input[type=text]" is natively supported by browser?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, cross-browser, css-selectors

In my CSS I have a rule that must be applied to all text fields (using the CSS3 selector `input[type=text]`.

I also use [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). Some browsers like Internet Explorer 6 does not support that form for CSS selector. So my workaround is to add an extra classname in CSS:

```
input[type=text], .workaround_classname{
  /* css styling goes here */
}
```

And via jQuery then add the CSS class:

```
$('input[type=text]').addClass('workaround_classname');
```

The Question is: How do I make sure this rule only is invoked when CSS3 selectors are not natively supported?

Comment: just thought I'd let you know that `[attr=val]` is not a CSS3 selector, it is 2.1, and supported by all modern browsers. What's new in CSS3 is `[attr^=val]` and similar RegEx-like selectors.

Comment: @Vincent: I said modern, didn't I :p

Comment: @peirix: Thanks for clarifying! CSS2.1 rules were apparently not in focus by IE team back in 2001 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using conditional comments in my javascript file. This way I could address IE6 and apply the CSS class

```
$(function(){
  //add css class to input[type=text] fields if the selector is not natively supported
    // IE6 hack: Since some CSS selectors are not working, we simulate with class names.
    /*@cc_on@if (@_jscript_version <= 5.6)
    $('input[type=text],input[type=password],input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox]').
        each(function() { $(this).addClass('type_' + this.type); });
    @end@*/

});
```

This way, I end up with added class names for all form fields:

```
.type_text{}
.type_radio{}
.type_checkbox{}
.type_password{}
```

Comment: really, doing this is actually worse than adding classes to elements for all browsers when you can't use some css selectors. Also, more javascript in ie6 means less performance ... :)

Comment: Vincent, you miss an important point: I want no extra work and no extra unnecessary steps performed by developers implementing my styles. Developers should just focus on thinking: "i want a text field here..." and NOT having to remember to add an extra `class="type_text"` or similar. I have seen that going wrong so many times.

Comment: Another thing that made me favor this idea is that there is absolutely no modification to existing fields. And absolutely no way of forgetting to set the classname.

Answer (score 3):

Why not set some useless css style and check if the style was applied. Only add the workaround class to the elements that don't have this style applied.

Only problem is I can't come up with a "useless" style you can use :-)

Comment: I think the @conditional comments for IE6 can do the trick. (see my own answer below). This way, the styles can be applied to all text fields only -- and only if the browser does not support it natively. In a 8-10 years when IE6 is really phased out, then the @conditional comment can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to incorporate something like you speak of:

http://www.w3avenue.com/2009/07/02/detect-support-for-css3-html5-with-modernizr/

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have

```
input.workaround_classname{
  /* css styling goes here */
}
```

then add `workaround_classname` to all text inputs in your markup.

The selectors you could use are (I think the second is probably the one that would be easiest to understand what it was selecting for someone else reading the code)

```
$('input:text')
// or
$('input:text.workaround_classname')
// or
$('input.workaround_classname')
```

Then no detection is needed and you won't be relying on JavaScript to add the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.geocities.com/seanmhall2003/css3/detect.html. You should do this for each property.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to know "does this browser support CSS3 selectors". All you can do is detecting the browser and browser version.

Modernizr will not help you as you can't detect if a particular CSS selector works in a .css file. (Or you have to check if a particular CSS property from your CSS selector is applied and THIS is really ugly !)

BUT! Here the easiest way would be to forget about CSS 2.1 selectors like [attr=] in .css files as it's not widely supported. And if you have to write for browsers that doesn't support them (like Internet Explorer 6), you just can't use them.

So, add a class for everyone. Your code will be easier to understand, otherwise you'll always add unnecessary JavaScript code.

I understand I'm not answering you, but this is b-a-d!